# WSO2 IDENTITY SERVER SCIM2.0 API - GET USER BY ID

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, scim2

I want to use the wso2 SCIM2.0 API for CRUD operations on my users.
When I call the API to get ALL the users, it works, but when I try to call the API to get a specific User by its ID, it returns a 403 forbidden error.

The API I'm calling is this one:
https://localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/scim2/Users/29ae81f4-37eb-4e5c-a3c9-33cba98f4f47

and I'm passing the access token generated with the scope: internal_user_mgt_list

and the users logged in that is trying to call the API has all the User Managment permissions.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem. The documentation specifies the wrong scope. The required scope is not internal_user_mgt_list but **internal_user_mgt_view**

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. We will fix the docs ASAP.